# Is there any chance Chrome OS will support .NET framework?

Tags: .net, google-chrome, operating-system, google-chrome-os

Is there any chance Chrome OS will support .NET framework?
Or will we need to learn Java...

Comment: Being Linux based it could run Mono, but the hardware profile they are targeting says it is unlikely.

Comment: @Godeke: That is assuming it is "just" Linux. From what they've said so far, it sounds like a very basic Linux kernel, with little more functionality than what it takes to get online and run a web browser. So Mono compatibility is hardly a given. It might work, it might be made to work over time, or it might not.

Comment: What sort of .NET code would you want to develop for it? Doesn't seem like a good platform match..

Comment: How is this not programming related?  I can't actually think of any other category that it would be put under.

Comment: As the OS isn't even complete yet this could go either way. There is nothing stopping Google putting a port of .Net in the OS but I doubt they will.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A chance? Sure. But one so tiny that it isn't worth thinking about.

The publicity so far suggests that it will do nothing except run Chrome. This will give the usual APIs (<del>including Google Gears</del>Gear has been deprecated by Google), but everything will have to run in the browser.

You don't have to learn Java. Client side web programming is almost entirely based around JavaScript (which has about as much in common with Java as carpets have in common with cars.)

Of course, you will still be able to use .NET on the server should you so wish. Personally, I'll stick to Perl.

Comment: My car has has a carpet. Does that mean that Java has a JavaScript?

Comment: .NET will run on chromeOS at some point soon. "http://code.google.com/games/technology-nacl.html"

Comment: @Martin — Yes, [it does](http://www.mozilla.org/rhino/) ;)

Comment: @zezba9000 — No sign of .NET in that article.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt it will support either. Well, maybe java browser applets or Silverlight/moonlight, but even that's a stretch.  From the sounds of things it will be just barely enough to get the Chrome browser running, and that's it's.  No other apps or even desktop environment.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on a lot of things unfortunately.  Most particularly what version of the .Net Framework.

Will it support the Microsoft version of the framework?  Unlikely as it won't be based on the Windows OS.

As far as I know, it will be a Linux based product so it has a higher chance of supporting a project like Mono.  But given this will be a very stripped down OS, targeting smaller devices, it may end up needing to target a stripped down version of mono (similar to the compact framework).

But this is mainly idle speculation until a bit more is known about Chrome OS.